# Why is this set connected?

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand something about a proof of that if $X_i$ is a connected space for every $i\in I$, then $X=\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ is connected.

It is this: Let $x\in X$. Define $C$ the set of all $y\in X$ such that there exists $D\subseteq X$ connected such that $x,y\in D$.

"Then $C$ is connected, because it is union of connected subsets of $X$".

What are the connected sets $C_j\subseteq X$ such that $C=\bigcup_jC_j$?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $C$ is a collection of connected sets with nonempty intersection. Then $\bigcup C$ is connected. To see this, consider a continuous function $f:\bigcup C\to  \{0,1\}$ and pick a point $x\in\bigcap C$. The function $f$ restricted to each element of $C$ must be constant, and it takes the value $f(x)$. But then $f$ itself must be constant, of value $f(x)$.

The claim is still true if $C=(C_i)$ is countable and $C_i\cap C_{i+1}\neq 0$, but not necessarily true if we only assume the $C_i$ are connected. For example, two disjoint intervals in $\Bbb R$ are connected, but their union is not.

Answer (score 0):

$C$ (really $C_x$, as it depends on the point $x$) is *defined* as the set of all $y \in X$ such that there exists $D \subseteq X$ (which I shall call $D_{x,y}$, for reference, to show that different $y$ can have different $D$, and all depends on the $x$) such that $D_{x,y}$ is connected and $x,y \in D_{x,y}$.

Then $C_x = \bigcup \{D_{x,y}: y \in C_x\}$. The inclusion from left to right is clear as every $y \in C_x$ is in its "own" $D_{x,y}$ so in that union. If $z \in D_{x,y}$, then we could have picked $D_{x,z} = D_{x,y}$ to see that $z \in C_x$ as well. So all sets $D_{x,y}$ are subsets of $C_x$, so the union is too, and this shows the other inclusion.

This shows that $C$ (really $C_x$) is the union of connected subsets (the $D_{x,y}$) that (important!) *all* contain $x$, so their union is connected (as a standard theorem on unions of connected sets shows, proved in Pedro's post).

This construction/definition can be done in all topological spaces, and $C_x$ is called the connected component of the point $x \in X$, and is the maximal connected subset (in terms of inclusion) that contains $x$. This set is never empty, as $x \in C_x$ is witnessed by the always connected $D_{x,x} = \{x\}$.